# Scale patterns in Gnuplot (without resizing the whole output)

Tags: gnuplot

I want to create a plot with the `eps` terminal using patterns to fill the area between some curves, for example using these commands:

```
set terminal eps size 4, 4
set output "plot.eps"
plot x**2 with filledcurves fs pattern 4
```

Is there any way to scale the pattern, i.e., make the filling lines in the example more or less dense without changing the output size?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with a trick, but at present I am able to do it only by hands.
Considering that:
 The `postscript` [is a language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript).
The `eps` file is text readable.
At the line 443 of the output generated by your command there you can read

```
1.28 w
```

If you modify changing the value you will change the thickness of one of the filling pattern.
For example I tryed:

```
5.28 w
```

Here below the images (converted in `png`) with the default value of 1.28 and with a modified one of 5.28.

[image: Default value 1.28 w]
[image: Modified value 5.28 w]

ps> `gnuplot` Version 4.6 patchlevel 4.

---

It was inside this `CairoPattern` block.

```
/CairoPattern {
  q
1 g
0 0 8 8 rectfill
1 0 0 rg
1.28 w
0 J
0 j
[] 0.0 d
10 M q 1 0 0 -1 0 8 cm
4 0 m 4 8 l S Q
  Q
}
```

Reference

- The postscript [manual](https://www.adobe.com/products/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf)